# how to check if shopify session has expired?

Tags: shopify

say I have this call in my code:

`products = shopify.Product.find()`

which works if I am just logged in, but after some time it starts failing with an error saying `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`. I think this happens because the session expires and my code does not check that.

is there a way to check if shopify session has expired? I store the store URL and the authentication token in my webapp2 session thus:

`self.session['shopify'] = {
    'shop_url': shopify_session.url,
    'access_token': shopify_session.token
    }`

are there any other properties that I need to store in my web session that I can use to check if the shopify session has expired?

Comment: The access token used in the `X-Shopify-Access-Token` header shouldn't expire. Are you using the [shopify_python_api](https://github.com/shopify/shopify_python_api) library? What is returning None, or where does the error occur if in a library?  Because presumably shopify.Product isn't None.

Comment: @Dylan, thanks for your response. it was a bug in my code. i was not setting up and activating shopify session correctly. so shopify.Product was returning None. it would be helpful if instead of NoneType error there were more informative message, but I suppose it comes from pyactiveresource, not your adapter. thanks.

Comment: @akonsu I am facing a similar problem, what was your issue and how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your access mode, if you want a permanent access token, you should use **offline access** mode, online access mode get expires after the user session expires.

https://shopify.dev/concepts/about-apis/authentication#api-access-modes

Answer (score -1):

**Shopify** `access_token` never expires, the one that expires or been reset is **your** session.

If you are using a shared hosting then the probability of resetting the session is much higher since they reset the application pool very frequent.

If this is the case then you should consider using persistent session rather than memory session. If you are using .NET then you can read [ASP.NET State Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx) and [Configure SQL Server for ASP.NET SQL Server Session State](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604).